# Cookies PHP CURL store in clients side

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have proxy, and i want to store `cookies` in clients `cookies` but when i using the following code its dont works, they dont stores in browser, and if they store somewhere in server anyway they dont works.

```
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
$headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
curl_close($ch);
$responseHeaders = substr($response, 0, $headerSize);
preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie: (.*?)=(.*?);/i",$responseHeaders,$cookies);
array_shift($cookies); //removes first
$i = 0;
foreach($cookies[0] as $name) {
    $curl_cookies .= $name."=".$cookies[1][$i].";";

//  if(!isset($_COOKIE[$name])) {
//      setcookie( $name, $cookies[1][$i], time()+(60*60*24*30) );
//  }
//  elseif($_COOKIE[$name] != $cookies[1][$i]) {
//      setcookie( $name, $cookies[1][$i], time()+(60*60*24*30) );      
//  }

    $i++;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $curl_cookies);
```

When i using  commented code, and remove

`$curl_cookies .= $name."=".$cookies[1][$i].";";`

*and*

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $curl_cookies);`

Cookies are stores in the clients `cookies` but dont works from websites too.
But when i replace that code to :

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
```

All works fine, but `cookies` are the same for any user, ofc i can use something like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ip."cookie.txt");
```

But that way is makes large count of `.txt` files for each `ip` which visit my proxy.

Any idea how to storage `cookies` into **clients** `cookies` and make them work?

Comment: If you want to issue a cookie to the client in response to the client’s request, then use `setcookie` function.

Comment: Thanks. But im using `setcookie` but website, which im opening throught `proxy` dont manage them, but i have them in my browser.

Comment: _Because_ you are proxying the requests, you will have to pass on any headers that your proxy script receives from the server to the client, and vice versa in the other direction … that’s how a proxy _works_.

Comment: Thanks. How should i add `$responseHeaders` to page header? By the function `header()` ?

Comment: Im writing `preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie: (.*)\b/',$responseHeaders,$cookies);` by `header()` but its now working still.